# Key length not 128/192/256 bits

Tags: c#, ios, certificate, mdm

I am trying to encrypt the final mdm profile using the Identity certificate(got in the response after SCEP payload). 
I have the following code:

```
context.Request.InputStream.CopyTo(deviceResponse);

  var signer = new SignedCms();
  signer.Decode(deviceResponse.ToArray());
  X509Certificate2 certificate = signer.Certificates[0];
  string str= sonething; //my final configuraton profile                       
 encryptedProfile = AESEncryption(str, cerificate.GetPublicKeyString(), true, Encoding.Default, pkcs);
```

I got the exception: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.

How can I encrypt the final profile(I am using Bouncy Castle library)?

Regards

Mag

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your "cerificate.GetPublicKeyString()" is not returning a key with the propper length (128/192/256 bits). The minimum you need is 128 bits (16 bytes = 16 length).

Answer (score 0):

This should not be AES encryption. It has to be CMSAlgorithm.DES_EDE3_CBC encrypted.

Comment: This is the way it needs to be done in Bouncycastle which worked for me. Simply its should be encrypted in CMSAlgorithm.DES_EDE3_CBC with iOS identity certificate. Then the normal sign happens as the previous step. For that the payload needs to be Base64 encoded. Better check the ruby companion file given by Apple to compare this. Normal encryption will not work in this scenario in my opinion.

Comment: That does not match with the given exception message, unless somebody invented 256 bit DES keys. That does not invalidate the answer in any way, but it seems to be an inconsistency between the Q & A.